# Difference between a const reference parameter and const parameter in the context of a function

Tags: c++

I tend to use `const reference` parameters when calling functions assuming this would be efficient since copies of the same wouldn't not be made. Accidentally I changed the function parameter in a function that previously had a `const reference` parameter to `const` now, and I observed that the code size is reduced upon compilation.

To check this, I looked into the assembly of a [MWE](https://godbolt.org/z/n4vGzx77M):

```
#include <cstdint>

void foo(const int n)
{
    int a = n + 1;
}

void foo(const int& n)
{
    int a = n + 1;
}
```

On line 19 of the generated assembly code, I see an additional step `ldr r3, [r3]` in the case of `void foo(const int& n)` when compared to  `void foo(const int n)`. I assume this is the reference to variable `n` (I could be wrong, please forgive me).

So, my question is, why is the code larger when passing via reference and also what method is efficient?

Comment: What optimization level?

Comment: A reference is, basically, a pointer? There's extra work to dereference the pointer?

Comment: @0x5453 O0 optimization

Comment: General rule of thumb - pass primitive types by value and everything else by reference.
When the value fits into a single register, it is more efficient than having to 'lookup' what was the value in memory at the address pointed by the reference. (The way I see it, a reference is just a pointer to some memory address but can't be null.)

Comment: @AlexG Seems true. Used a `void foo(const int* const n)` prototype and it behaves exactly like a reference.

Comment: `ldr r3, [r3]` is _dereferencing_ your `const int &n`.  `r3` holds the `int` in your first function, but holds the memory location of the `int` in your second function, so there's an extra step to get the actual value, since it was not passed to the function.

Comment: I'm surprised I can't find a good previous answer too this. There are generic computing answers but I was expecting something C++. Anyone?

Comment: With rare exceptions lvalue references to const should usually be replaced with passing the value by value. The only scenario I can think of where a lvalue reference to a const primitive could be necessary would be if the address is relevant...

Comment: As a slight aside, declaring a parameter passed by value as `const` doesn't really achieve anything.  In fact, I'd call it an anti-pattern.

Comment: @PaulSanders Well, in my case, MISRA guidelines forces me to do so

Comment: @mmcblk1 How silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reference can be understood as something in between a name alias and a pointer.
From [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/101406/10947572):

> A compiler keeps "references" to variables, associating a name with a memory address. Its job is to translate any variable name to a memory address when compiling.
> When you create a reference, you only tell the compiler that you assign another name to the pointer variable; that's why references cannot "point to null". A variable cannot be, and not be at the same time.
> Pointers are variables; they contain the address of some other variable, or can be null. The important thing is that a pointer has a value, while a reference only has a variable that it is referencing.

- On a 32 bit-machine, a `pointer` has 4 bytes (`4*8 = 32` bits) while on a 64-bit machine a `pointer` has 8 bytes (`8*8 = 64` bits), because that is the size of a single memory address.
- On a 32 bit-machine, `int`, `long` are each 4 bytes (32 bits) quantities.
  On most 64-bit systems, `long` becomes 8 bytes (64 bits), **but** `int` remains 32-bit (4 bytes).

[Speaking about primitive types, the size of `char` is fixed at 1 byte (or `CHAR_BIT = 8` bits) explicitly in the C++ standard.]

Given that passing a `const reference` as function parameter requires the compiler to dig for the memory address of the referenced variable, in case the variable is a primitive type such as `int` or `char` the digging in memory (`pointer` is 8 bytes) is going to be more expensive than passing the variable itself by value (4 bytes for `int`, 1 byte for `char`).

The question is about the efficiency of parameters passed by `const reference`.
Of course, a function accepting a parameter by *non-const* `reference` would have the advantage - unrelated to efficiency - of allowing modifications of the referenced variable to persist, when control goes back to the caller.

Comment: "*On 64-bit systems, `long` becomes 8 bytes (64 bits)*" - that depends on platform and even compiler. For instance, Windows defines `DWORD` and `LONG` as 32bit even on a 64-bit system, but they are both defined in terms of `(unsigned) long`, which means `long` should always be 32bit. However, I've seen it go both ways, where some compilers treat `long` as 32bit on a 64bit system, and some compilers treat `long` as 64bit on a 64bit system. The C++ standard does not dictate what exact size `long` must be (same with all other integer types), so it is *implementation-defined*.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'll modify "On most platforms ..."

Comment: @RemyLebeau Specifically, >= `int`, I believe.

Comment: @PaulSanders Well, yes, the standard dictates `sizeof(long) >= sizeof(int)`, but it doesn't dictate exact sizes for `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(long)`.